# Returning the number of likes of a facebook page using Graph API in Python to my .html page

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to display the number of followers of my facebook page in the homepage of a site built in django.

(I've only built in rails before, so I'm a real noob with python/danjo, I've been stuck on this for two weeks).

I've been using this code from [this post](http://www.idiotinside.com/2015/02/13/get-number-of-likes-of-a-facebook-page-using-graph-api-in-python/):

```
import urllib2
import json

def get_page_data(page_id,access_token):
    api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/"
    fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+page_id+"?fields=id,name,likes,link&access_token="+access_token
    try:
        api_request = urllib2.Request(fb_graph_url)
        api_response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)

        try:
            return json.loads(api_response.read())
        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return "JSON error"

    except IOError, e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            return e.code
        elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            return e.reason

page_id = "idiotinside" # username or id
token = "TOKEN"  # Access Token
page_data = get_page_data(page_id,token)

print "Page Name:"+ page_data['name']
print "Likes:"+ str(page_data['likes'])
print "Link:"+ page_data['link']
```

And it prints on console perfectly fine, but when I try to return it to fb.html I get:

> IndentationError at /
>   unexpected indent (views.py, line 67)

and when I try to indent it at the same level of *print "Link:"+ page_data['link']* I get:

> SyntaxError at /
>   'return' outside function (views.py, line 67)

And if I indent everything like this:

```
def get_page_data(page_id,access_token):

  import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()    

   api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/"
   fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+page_id+"?fields=id,name,likes,link&access_token="+access_token

   try:
       api_request = urllib2.Request(fb_graph_url)
       api_response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)

       try:
           return json.loads(api_response.read())
       except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
           return "JSON error"

   except IOError, e:
       if hasattr(e, 'code'):
           return e.code
       elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
           return e.reason
   import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

   page_id = "xxxxxxxxx" # username or id
   token = "xxxxx"  # Access Token
   page_data = get_page_data(page_id,token)

   print "Page Name:"+ page_data['name']
   print "Likes:"+ str(page_data['likes'])
   print "Link:"+ page_data['link']

   return render_to_response(page_data['name'], str(page_data['likes']), page_data['link'])
```

That **ipdb** under *def get_page_data* doesn't even get fired.

I tried finding an alternative solution by working with facebook-sdk 0.4.0 and fb 0.2.0 but their documentation is not clear/tutorial-like enough for a beginner like me.

Please, help help of whichever kind will be much appreciated...

Comment: Seems like this has little to do with Facebook so far – and that you should to go read up on the basics of the python syntax first.

Comment: The code blocks you've provided show that the imports have a different indentation to the code below it. Indentation matters in python.

Comment: Thank you both, I knew my indentation was off and I spent days trying to find examples of usage to learn from - having found none I hope to receive practical help here, not to much avail I see. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I received help from a senior dev, here's the solution:

first set your url:

```
url(r'^(?P<page_name>fb)/$', 'pages.views.facebook_page', name='facebook-page'),
```

Then in pages/views.py:

```
def facebook_page(request, page_name):
page_id = ".............." # username or id
token = "................"  # Access Token
context = get_page_data(page_id,token)

return  render_to_response('pages/fb.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def get_page_data(page_id,access_token):
api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/"
fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+page_id+"?fields=id,name,likes,link&access_token="+access_token

try:
    api_request = urllib2.Request(fb_graph_url)
    api_response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)

    try:
        return json.loads(api_response.read())
    except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
        return "JSON error"

except IOError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'):
        return e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        return e.reason
```

And it can be recalled in the view like this:

```
<li class="social"><h3>Likes: {{likes}}</h3></li>
```